# how to rename key value in python

Tags: python

how can i rename key value in python?

i have this code :

```
t =  { u'last_name': [u'hbkjh'], u'no_of_nights': [u'1'], u'check_in': [u'2012-03-19'], u'no_of_adult': [u'', u'1'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'05e5bdb542c3be7515b87e8160c347a0'], u'memo': [u'kjhbn'], u'totalcost': [u'1800.0'], u'product': [u'4'], u'exp_month': [u'1'], u'quantity': [u'2'], u'price': [u'900.0'], u'first_name': [u'sdhjb'], u'no_of_kid': [u'', u'0'], u'exp_year': [u'2012'], u'check_out': [u'2012-03-20'], u'email': [u'ebmalifer@agile.com.ph'], u'contact': [u'3546576'], u'extra_test1': [u'jknj'], u'extra_test2': [u'jnjl'], u'security_code': [u'3245'], u'extra_charged': [u'200.0']}
key = {str(k): str(v[0]) for k,v in t.iteritems() if k.startswith('extra_')}
array = []
for val in key:
    data = str(val) + ' = ' + key[val] + ','
    array.append(data)
print array
```

it give me this :

```
["extra_charged = 200.0,", "extra_test1 = jknj,", "extra_test2 = jnjl,"]
```

what should i do to remove the `'extra_'` and it makes the output like this:

```
["CHARGED = 200.0,", "TEST1 = jknj,", "TEST2 = jnjl,"]
```

can anyone have an idea about my case?
thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found this `.replace()`

and i do like this ..

```
data = str(val).replace("extra_","").upper() + ' = ' + key[val] + ','
```

Comment: That's probably safer than using [6:], and would easily allow you to change the string using a variable in both the initial key= and data= lines, though replace is slower for sure.  I'll leave mine alone as the "faster-executing" method.

Answer (score 6):

So, array indexing can strip off the first 6 characters, and upper() should uppercase it.

Replace that one data= line with:

```
data = str(val)[6:].upper() + ' = ' + key[val] + ','
```

that should work.

Comment: As I said below, this is the "faster" solution, but using a variable for the text to replace with replace() below is not bad.